# Symbol which looks like $\oint$ which marks the beginning of a section/chapter?

Tags: symbols

How do I make the symbol which looks like $\oint$ which marks the beginning of a section/chapter? Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14 In the list of symbols, `\S` = § appears in table 3 at page 9.

Comment: A little bit more, general info about this sign, in case you're interested: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign

Comment: I think it's re-opening this posting since the symbol in question is *not* a math symbol at all but, instead, a vertical superimposition of two `S` characters. The reference to `\oint` is admittedly a bit unfortunate.

Comment: This question is even answered. Unless OP means anything else but §, it is fine to leave it closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[image: section symbol]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \S 1
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very easy rep :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Obviously. I could delete it. I figure there is a duplicate somewhere but answering was quicker. Probably should go back to answering anonymously but that is something of a pain. (Actually, sometimes it is literally impossible. But when it is not impossible, it is a huge pain.)

Comment: No, no, don't delete it. I learned that this is called `section sign`, whereas in German it means `Paragraph`, which is actually used only for numbering laws in jurisdiction, not in the sense of `\paragraph`